# Get objects from aws s3 bucket in Typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get object from aws s3 bucket but I got null data response.
My code as follows:

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
public async getObjects() { 
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: "MY_KEY_ID",
      secretAccessKey: "MY_SECRET_KEY",
      region: "eu-central-1"
    });

    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const response = await s3.listObjects({Bucket: 'my-bucket'});
    console.log(response);
  }
```

The response I got from debugger:

```
 response:
   Response {
     request: [Circular],
     data: null,
     error: null,
     retryCount: 0,
     redirectCount: 0,
     httpResponse:
      HttpResponse {
        statusCode: undefined,
        headers: {},
        body: undefined,
        streaming: false,
        stream: null },
     maxRetries: 3,
     maxRedirects: 10 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`s3.listObjects` does not return promise, you should call it in a different way (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property):

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
public getObjects() { 
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: "MY_KEY_ID",
      secretAccessKey: "MY_SECRET_KEY",
      region: "eu-central-1"
    });

    let s3 = new AWS.S3();
    s3.listObjects({Bucket: 'my-bucket'}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: It turns out that I can't reach 443 port of aws s3, hence can't access the data.

Comment: If you want to access S3 from EC2 you can use VPC Endpoint to connect using private aws network (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpce-gateway.html). It will allow you to keep restrictive firewalls facing public internet (if that was the issue in your case)

Comment: I request my company to allow the connection and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.promise()` in the end.

`const response = await s3.listObjects({Bucket: 'my-bucket'}).promise();`

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-async-await.html